# Alternative to or recommended better use of Classie

Tags: javascript

Let me start of by saying I am not much a coder and pretty much fumble my way through using javascript libraries and jquery etc. I discovered and have been using classie.js to add classes to divs and elements on in my html when they are appear at a certain scroll distance on the page. so in my header i have a LOT of scripts to add and remove classes... for example:

```
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 100,
            feature = document.querySelector("#welcomediv");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.remove(feature,"welcomewish");
        } else {
                classie.add(feature,"welcomewish");    
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            feature = document.querySelector("#slidetext");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.remove(feature,"welcomewish");
        } else {
                classie.add(feature,"welcomewish");    
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 50,  <?php /*?>130<?php */?>
            feature = document.querySelector("#roundfeatures-panel");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(feature,"appearnow");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(feature,"appearnow")) {
                classie.remove(feature,"appearnow");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 140,
            feature = document.querySelector("#roundfeatures-panel");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(feature,"expandnow");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(feature,"expandnow")) {
                classie.remove(feature,"expandnow");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 1000,
            feature = document.querySelector("#futureevents-panel");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(feature,"appearnow");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(feature,"appearnow")) {
                classie.remove(feature,"appearnow");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 1400,
            feature = document.querySelector("#viewallworkshops");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(feature,"slideinnow");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(feature,"slideinnow")) {
                classie.remove(feature,"slideinnow");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 2250,
            feature = document.querySelector("#subscribe-panel");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(feature,"appearnow");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(feature,"appearnow")) {
                classie.remove(feature,"appearnow");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
```

(...and there are even more! and if i had my way, i'd probably add more still, because i like what i can do with the elements by adding and removing classes in this way. but if feels clunky and messy and is very hard to maintain.)

and then obviously my html elements on the page.

The problems with this are:

1) ugly scripts in my header.. is there a way i can condense the scripts in some way and retain their purpose?

2) Whenever i add new elements or take them out of the page, i have to manually change the number (shrinkOn) associated with each instance. This becomes a nightmare to be honest. It would be better if i could in some way say "when this element appears on the page" or "100px after this element appears on the page" rather than stating a strict number of pixels the page has scrolled. IS this possible with classie, or do i need to look at another option?

thanks in advance and i hope this question is appropriate.

Comment: *"ugly scripts in my header"* Well, for one thing, they shouldn't be in your header (I assume you mean the `head` element), they [should be](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) at the bottom of the HTML just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. This is only tangential to your question, though.

Comment: Also, repeatedly writing to `window.onload` will **replace** the previous callback, not add to a list. Only the last one assigned will be called when the event occurs.

Comment: You've tagged your question `jquery` but there's no jQuery code in your examples, and lots of code where jQuery would likely be used. Do you actually use jQuery?

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand what is the expected result. To be honest, by applying a TL;DR method, by just scrolling the code above, I see and endless override of the init function and an endless **replace** of the window.onload . It would be nicer to see what is the expected result to me (also, check your tags, I don't see neither some CSS nor some jQuery here)

Comment: I apologize, i meant javascript and not jquery (for my tags).

Comment: I tagged it CSS because the code refers to divs to whcih i am adding classes.... I assumed that would be considered related enough to css, but perhaps i shoudln;t have tagged it so. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that code can readily be parameterized, as all the blocks are doing the same thing.

Have an array of updates to do:

```
var scrollUpdates = [];
```

A function to add each update (this is purely for convenience, you could directly add them above):

```
addScrollUpdate(featureSelector, shrinkOn, className) {
    scrollUpdates.push({
        featureSelector: featureSelector,
        shrinkOn: shrinkOn,
        className: className
    });
}
```

One handler handles them:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    scrollUpdates.forEach(function(update) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            feature = document.querySelector(update.featureSelector);
        if (distanceY > update.shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(feature, update.className);
        } else {
            if (classie.has(feature, update.className)) {
                classie.remove(feature, update.className);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And you add each one like this:

```
addScrollUpdate("#welcomediv", 100, "welcomewish");
```

Putting it all together in *one* `window` `load` handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var scrollUpdates = [];

    addScrollUpdate(featureSelector, shrinkOn, className) {
        scrollUpdates.push({
            featureSelector: featureSelector,
            shrinkOn: shrinkOn,
            className: className
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        scrollUpdates.forEach(function(update) {
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                feature = document.querySelector(update.featureSelector);
            if (distanceY > update.shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(feature, update.className);
            } else {
                if (classie.has(feature, update.className)) {
                    classie.remove(feature, update.className);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    addScrollUpdate("#welcomediv", 100, "welcomewish");
    addScrollUpdate("#slidetext", 300, "welcomewish");
    // ...and so on...
};
```

---

**However**, I wouldn't use the `window` `load` event for this, that happens very late in the page load process. Instead, I'd put the `script` tag at the **end** of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and run it immediately in an inline-invoked function expression:

```
(function() {
    // the code here
})();
```

---

Side note: I don't know Classie, but you probably don't need the `has` test before calling `remove`.

Comment: Thank you immensely. This is exactly the kind of answer and advice I was hoping for. I am not familiar enough with javascript to really understand it, but i suspected it would be possible to combine it in some way like this. I will take everyone's advice and put it in the bottom of the page too. THANK YOU!